# How to setup one live stream composed of multiple videos?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video

Can anyone give me some direction on this?  I'd like to set something up where let's say I have a directory (or database) of videos.  I want a live stream to play those videos.  And then if I add videos to the database it automatically plays it next in the stream.  I would also like to have an interface where I could load one on the fly and it would stop the current video and go to the new one.   Preferably PHP or Python.

I'm not quite sure where to begin on this.  I know I can't just throw the videos on a CDN and be done with it.  I think I need some special live streaming software?  But I don't want to make this overly complicated.

oh and something that can play on desktops and iphone/ipad would be greatttt :)

Any help is appreciated!